# How to composite large images stored on S3 in ImageMagick from EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, parallel-processing, imagemagick, celery

I have an ongoing list of image processing tasks to do, using ImageMagick to composite large individual graphic files (20MB each). These images are currently stored on S3 (approximately 2.5GB in total).

I was thinking to use multiple EC2 instances to process the tasks, composite the images and upload the output file to S3.

The problem with this setup is that ImageMagick needs the file library to be local (on the machine). Currently images are on S3, which means each instance would need to download a copy of the images from S3, slowing down the whole process.

What's the best way to share this image library to all nodes?

Comment: Do you have to do this just once, or often? What does one single ImageMagick command look like? What do you use to manage the queue? Would all EC2 nodes need all images, or are the tasks splittable such that you might only need a subset of the images at each node? What is the appropriate total amount of work - e.g. produce 80 output images each one by compositing 20 input images of 3,000x2,000 pixels.

Comment: Question updated with additional info and example commands

Comment: when you say "file library" do you mean a library of image files or do you mean a software library for file operations?

Comment: And what exactly are you asking? There seem to be 3 questions here: 1) is there a faster way of doing this file operation than with ImageMagick 2) should I use Celery/RabbitMQ or SQS 3) is there a better way of sharing this file library. As it stands your question is too broad - you seem to be looking for a whole design - this site is for answering specific, single topic questions - you should probably ask 3 separate questions and this will probably get you the information you need.

Comment: Also, what are you actually trying to minimise? The volume of S3 data transferred? The total EC2 running time? The start-to-end time that users experience?

Comment: I was trying to give a bit of context to the question and responding to the questions by Mark. I'm asking 3) is there a better way of sharing this file library

Comment: A little simple maths tells me you have around 100-150 images, correct? Before you try optimising anything, you need to benchmark. I would try downloading 1, then 2, then 4, then 8 images in parallel and seeing if the performance is limited by bandwidth or latency. If it is latency, try downloading 4-16 images in parallel with `GNU Parallel` it is pretty simple. If that doesn't get you the performance, you may have to try to maintain a mirror of your 2.5GB on each node and checksum files before use to see if they are current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider also the following points:

1. You can do any processing of ImageMagick files completely in memory by "saving" any input image in the special format `MPR:` (*Magick Pixel Register*). For details see this answer: **"[ImageMagick multiple operations in single invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29738251/359307)"**
2. ImageMagick can access remote images via `http://`.
3. You can put a *lot* of ImageMagick's operations into one single command line which also can produce multiple output files, and you can segment that command line into sub- or side-processes by using the parentheses syntax: `... \( IM side process \) ...` for the sub-/side-processes.

How you can streamline your overall process depends a lot about what exactly you want to do. However,

- the `MPR:` / `MPC:` technique can be very useful for this and probably avoid or minimize the need to use multiple EC2 instances;
- you cannot get around the step to somehow ship the input pixels to that instance of ImageMagick which should process them (so "downloading a copy" will always have to occur);
- you can minimize the number of downloads by storing the input under a series of `MPR:xy1`, `MPR:xy2` etc. labels in memory and then access all these multiple times *fast* from a long and well constructed ImageMagick command line which does any number of compositions you want.

---

### Example

To give an example. Consider having 10 TIFFs, and you want to create 3 different PDF files from these tiffs, each PDF containing a different set of pages made up from the 10 TIFFs. Normally you would run 3 commands:

```
convert 1.tif 3.tif 4.tif 8.tif 9.tif 10.tif -compress jpeg -quality 70 1out1.pdf
convert 2.tif 3.tif 4.tif 7.tif 8.tif  9.tif -compress jpeg -quality 70 1out2.pdf
convert 3.tif 4.tif 5.tif 7.tif 8.tif 10.tif -compress jpeg -quality 70 1out3.pdf
```

These 3 commands will have to load 6 TIFF files each (some TIFFs, like `3.tif` being used in all 3 commands). That is 18 I/O events.

Now consider this command alternative, which will run faster (I believe):

```
convert                         \
  1.tif +write mpr:t1  +delete  \
  2.tif +write mpr:t2  +delete  \
  3.tif +write mpr:t3  +delete  \
  4.tif +write mpr:t4  +delete  \
  5.tif +write mpr:t5  +delete  \
  6.tif +write mpr:t6  +delete  \
  7.tif +write mpr:t7  +delete  \
  8.tif +write mpr:t8  +delete  \
  9.tif +write mpr:t9  +delete  \
 10.tif +write mpr:t10 +delete  \
  \( mpr:t1 mpr:t3 mpr:t4 mpr:t8 mpr:t9 mpr:t10                \
                -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write 2out1.pdf \) \
  \( mpr:t2 mpr:t3 mpr:t4 mpr:t7 mpr:t8 mpr:t9                 \
                -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write 2out2.pdf \) \
  \( mpr:t3 mpr:t4 mpr:t5 mpr:t7 mpr:t8 mpr:t10                \
                -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write 2out3.pdf \) \
  null:
```

This command loads each of the 10 TIFFs only once (10 I/O events in total). It then writes each TIFF into an `MPR:` file with an appropriate label and then deletes the initial TIFF from the image sequence.

After this initial preparation ImageMagick will run 3 different, *parenthese-d* side-processing pipelines in sequence loading the required output pages as `MPR:` images, and create a PDF from each of them.

Above example is probably too limited in order to demonstrate a measurable advantage by using `MPR:`. Because the same results can also be achieved by this command:

```
convert  \
  1.tif  \
  2.tif  \
  3.tif  \
  4.tif  \
  5.tif  \
  6.tif  \
  7.tif  \
  8.tif  \
  9.tif  \
 10.tif  \
  \( -clone 0,2-3,7-9   -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write 3out1.pdf \) \
  \( -clone   1-3,6-8   -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write 3out2.pdf \) \
  \( -clone   2-4,6-7,9 -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write 3out3.pdf \) \
  null:
```

However, there is one more hook where some performance win may be acquired: the `-compress jpeg -quality 70` is applied 3 times to 6 (cloned, original) images each.

There may be some CPU cycles to be saved if we apply this operation to the TIFFs *before* they are written into the MPR registers. This way we apply that operation only to 10 TIFFs. Later we do not need to apply it any more when we write out the PDFs:

```
convert                         \
  -respect-parentheses          \
  1.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t1  +delete  \
  2.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t2  +delete  \
  3.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t3  +delete  \
  4.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t4  +delete  \
  5.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t5  +delete  \
  6.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t6  +delete  \
  7.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t7  +delete  \
  8.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t8  +delete  \
  9.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t9  +delete  \
 10.tif  -compress jpeg -quality 70 +write mpr:t10 +delete  \
  \( mpr:t1 mpr:t3 mpr:t4 mpr:t8 mpr:t9 mpr:t10  4out1.pdf \) \
  \( mpr:t2 mpr:t3 mpr:t4 mpr:t7 mpr:t8 mpr:t9   4out2.pdf \) \
  \( mpr:t3 mpr:t4 mpr:t5 mpr:t7 mpr:t8 mpr:t10  4out3.pdf \) \
  null:
```

### Update

Mark Setchell's comment was spot on. I had overlooked that before he mentioned it. It is probably faster (and certainly much less to type) to run the command like this:

```
convert                          \
  -respect-parentheses           \
  -compress jpeg -quality 70     \
  1.tif  +write mpr:t1  +delete  \
  2.tif  +write mpr:t2  +delete  \
  3.tif  +write mpr:t3  +delete  \
  4.tif  +write mpr:t4  +delete  \
  5.tif  +write mpr:t5  +delete  \
  6.tif  +write mpr:t6  +delete  \
  7.tif  +write mpr:t7  +delete  \
  8.tif  +write mpr:t8  +delete  \
  9.tif  +write mpr:t9  +delete  \
 10.tif  +write mpr:t10 +delete  \
  \( mpr:t1 mpr:t3 mpr:t4 mpr:t8 mpr:t9 mpr:t10  5out1.pdf \) \
  \( mpr:t2 mpr:t3 mpr:t4 mpr:t7 mpr:t8 mpr:t9   5out2.pdf \) \
  \( mpr:t3 mpr:t4 mpr:t5 mpr:t7 mpr:t8 mpr:t10  5out3.pdf \) \
  null:
```

You'll have to run your own benchmarks, with your own images, in your own environment, though, if you want to decide for whichever of the proposed commands you should prefer.

Comment: Nice answer - have my vote! One thought though, in your last example, I thought that `-compress` and `-quality` are *settings* so it should be enough just to set them once at the start and not repeat them, shouldn't it?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Thanks for the hint. I included it in my update.